# My mobile doesn't read my sd card

Tags: sd-card, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

My Sony Xperia Play doesn't read the memory card. It only says unavailable. Trying to format it didn't help either. I have tried many methods but the same problem occurs, so what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting it on a Mac or PC? Seems to work better than trying to format it in Android for some reason